# RxSwift Custom API Wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to wrap my API calls with RxSwift. I'm not using any third party library for these calls. The problem I'm facing is with custom error object. All API calls return a standard JSON error Object. This is an example:

```
{
  "error": {
     "code": 11001,
     "message": "Bad request",
     "errors": [
            "The accesstoken field is required."
            ]
  }
}
```

This is the code that will Send the API request

```
func CallAPI(withParameters parameters: [String : AnyObject]?,
             queryToSearchFor query: String?) -> Observable<AnyObject?>? {

    return Observable.create({ (observable) -> Disposable in
        ServerInterface.getRequest(
            withBaseURl: nil,
            withFunctionName: "util/load_companies/" + (query ?? ""),
            havingFunctionsParameters: nil,
            andHeaderParameters: parameters,
            withCompletionHandler: { (response) in
                guard response.responseCode == kSuccessCode else {
                    observable.on(.error( response.responseError  as! Error))
                    return
                }

                observable.on(.next(response.responseData))
                observable.on(.completed)
        })
        return Disposables.create {
            print("Request Cancelled")
        }
    })

}
```

`ServerInterface.getRequest()` has a completion handler of type `ServerInterfaceResponse` that contains a `ServerInterfaceError`. This object i want to `ObserverOn` when the API returns an error 
The problem appears on this line

`observable.on(.error( response.responseError  as! Error))`

At Runtime it crashes with error

> 'could not cast value of type ServerInterfaceError' to 'Error'

Here's my custom error object

```
class ServerInterfaceError: NSObject, Error {
    var errorCode: Int?
    var errorMessage: String?
    var errorDebugger: [String]?

    func error(_ code: Int?, message: String?,
               debugger: [String]?) -> ServerInterfaceError {

        let serverError = ServerInterfaceError.init()
        serverError.errorCode = code
        serverError.errorMessage = message
        serverError.errorDebugger = debugger

        return serverError

    }
}
```

Here's my custom APIResponse Object. it contains the a property `responseError` of type  ServerInterfaceError.

```
class ServerInterfaceResponse: NSObject {
    var responseCode: Int?
    var responseData: AnyObject?
    var responseMessage: String?
    var responseError: ServerInterfaceError?

    func response(_ code: Int?, data: AnyObject?, message: String?, error: ServerInterfaceError?) -> ServerInterfaceResponse {
         let serverResponse = ServerInterfaceResponse.init()
         serverResponse.responseCode = code
         serverResponse.responseData = data
         serverResponse.responseMessage = message
         serverResponse.responseError = error

        return serverResponse
    }

    override var description: String {
      return "Response Code = \(responseCode) | Response Data = \(responseData) | Response Message = \(responseMessage) | Response Error = {\(responseError)}"
    }
}
```

How can i send a custom object to the `observable.on(.error( ))`

Comment: What's the issue with "it fails to cast my custom error object to Error"? You don't say what the issue is.  Compile time error?  Runtime error?  You should be able to send your custom error as the error, however, you'll need to cast it back to your custom type since RxSwift only supports errors being simply `Error`.

Comment: @wasim, the error message mentions `ServerInterfaceResponseError`.  What does its declaration look like?  It must adopt `Error` protocol.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov I'm sorry it's not ``ServerInterfaceResponseError ``. it's  ``ServerInterfaceError ``. The class is provided in the question

Comment: What does `ServerInterfaceResponse` look like then?  In particular, it's input argument `response`, what is its type and that type's declaration?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the ``ServerInterfaceResponse`` class

Comment: I think that the problem is that `responseError` property is an optional `ServerInterfaceError?`.  Can you check if it is actually `nil` when the app crashes?

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. the function's returned type is marked as optional ``Observable<AnyObject?>? ``. also on the ``observable.on(.next())`` i'm passing ``response.responseData`` which is an optional. i have tested the API and was sure the ``response.responseError`` was not ``nil`` before crashing